# Probability of non-quilibrium states

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Considering the simple case of a perfect gas in a cubic cavity that reached equilibrium, is there a simple way to compute the probability that, at a given subsequent time, all gas molecules are in one given half of the cavity, given the total number of molecules, the size of the cavity and the temperature (or pressure) at equilibrium? Or, at least, bounds on that probability.

I also have the same question for the probability of such a non-equilibrium state to last longer than a given time.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of any particular molecule being in a specified half of the container is $\frac{1}{2}$, so, treating the disposition of molecules as independent, the probability of all $N$ molecules being in that half is $(\frac{1}{2})^N=2^{-N}$, is it not? This would be in the order of $10^{-22}$ for a gas at 300 K and atmospheric pressure in a container of volume $1 \times 10^{-3} \text{m}^3$. I offer this as a starting point.

What would be the probability of this occurring in the next minute, say? Very naïvely, one might define a characteristic time of $\frac{L}{v}$ in which *L* is the length or diameter of the vessel and $v$ is the molecular speed. $\frac{L}{v}$ would give a measure of the minimum clearance time for half the vessel. So in time *t* the number of opportunities for the molecules to occupy half the vessel would be $\frac{t}{\frac{L}{v}}=\frac{vt}{L}$. This is in the order of $10^6$ for air at room temperature in a cubic vessel of side length 0.1 m over a time of 1 minute. So one might think that the probability of all the molecules being in just half the container at some time in the next minute would be less than about $10^{-22}\times10^{6}=10^{-16}$.

I'm sure this approach is terribly flawed. Whether it's too flawed to be of any use whatsoever, I don't know. In any case I recommend you pursue the answer provided by StatisticalMechanic.

Comment: This is what I would also have taken as a starting point. I just wondered if it is correct to treat the disposition of molecules as independent. Is this implied by the "perfect gas" hypothesis?

Comment: Even in a perfect gas we have collisions, though for many purposes they can be ignored. I think this is such a purpose, but I wouldn't like to have to support this claim!. Incidentally, I've added to my answer (above).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Philip Wood for the case of a perfect gas at thermal equilibrium. However, the problem of persistence of such a "non-equilibrium state" is a different problem altogether.

This problem, as stated, falls in the category of Survival and Persistence problems and I suggest you have a look at the following references:

Persistence and First-Passage Properties in Non-equilibrium Systems (https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1195):

They look at simple models of non-equilibrium, set up the problem of persistence and do the analysis beautifully. While the continuous time-continuous space, many particle model (which is the problem of your interest) is not addressed, I think this will provide you with the tools to start looking at your problem yourself.

The Large Deviation approach to Statistical Mechanics (https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0327):

This is a beautifully written review article which shows how a sub-branch of Probability Theory (called Large Deviation Theory (LDT)) can be used as a language to express Statistical Physics. There are two kinds of problems addressed in LDT:
1. What is the probability of a rare event occurring? (say winning a lottery)
2. What does the distribution look like after a rare event has occurred? (e.g. what is your life going to look like after you've won the lottery?)
I think both these questions are relevant to answering your second question and I hope you find what you're looking for :)